# Why isn't this a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> The addition of integers $\mod N$ generates a group. For example,
>   under addition mod 5 the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ forms a group: $2 +
>  1= 3, 3 + 2 = 0, 4 + 3 = 2,$ and so on. The composition of the group
>   elements is defined by $j * k = j + k \mod 5$. The identity element
>   $I$ is denoted by $0$. The inverse of $2$, for example, is $3$, of $4$
>   is $1$, and so on. The group is clearly abelian.

This example is from A. Zee  Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists

I want to construct a subgroup.So first i take the identity element $0$. Now i have a trivial subgroup. Then i add another element $1$ also i need its inverse that is $4$. The inverse of $4$ is $1$.

$\{0, 1,  4\}$ is a group under addition mod5 , right ? It is closed, it has an identity, every element has an inverse, it is associative.

But it cannot be a group ( subgroup ) due to the Lagrange theorem because it has $3$ elements and $3$ does not divide $5$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not closed. $1+1=2,$ which is not in $\{0,1,4\}.$

Answer (score 4):

It's not closed because $1+1$ isn't in it.

Answer (score 2):

1+1=2 and 4+4=3 is not in your set. So it is not a semigroup.
Ok, now you can restrict your operation as, you will not alow a*a, i.e, if you say that the operation between same element is not allowed, i.e., 1+1 and 4+4 is not defined then {0,1,4} is closed. But it is not so much interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The group operation ( = group law ) $\color{red}{+}$ here is $a\color{red}{+}b = (a+b)\bmod 5$ and $+$ is the normal addition of integers. The set $G=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ together with $\color{red}{+}$ build a group $(G,\color{red}{+})$.

We can operate on all elements in the set $G=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and get the following

---

$0\color{red}{+}0 = (0+0)\bmod 5 = 0 = 0\color{red}{+}0 $

$0\color{red}{+}1 = (0+1)\bmod 5 = 1$

$0\color{red}{+}2 = (0+2)\bmod 5 = 2$

$0\color{red}{+}3 = (0+3)\bmod 5 = 3 $

$0\color{red}{+}4 = (0+4)\bmod 5 = 4$

---

$1\color{red}{+}0 = (1+0)\bmod 5 = 1 = 0\color{red}{+}1 $

$1\color{red}{+}1 = (1+1)\bmod 5 = 2 $

$1\color{red}{+}2 = (1+2)\bmod 5 = 3 $

$1\color{red}{+}3 = (1+3)\bmod 5 = 4 $

$1\color{red}{+}4 = (1+4)\bmod 5 = 0 $

---

$2\color{red}{+}0 = (2+0)\bmod 5 = 2 = 0\color{red}{+}2 $

$2\color{red}{+}1 = (2+1)\bmod 5 = 3 = 1\color{red}{+}2 $

$2\color{red}{+}2 = (2+2)\bmod 5 = 4 $

$2\color{red}{+}3 = (2+3)\bmod 5 = 0 $

$2\color{red}{+}4 = (2+4)\bmod 5 = 1 $

---

$3\color{red}{+}0 = (3+0)\bmod 5 = 3 = 0\color{red}{+}3 $

$3\color{red}{+}1 = (3+1)\bmod 5 = 4 = 1\color{red}{+}3 $

$3\color{red}{+}2 = (3+2)\bmod 5 = 0 = 2\color{red}{+}3  $

$3\color{red}{+}3 = (3+3)\bmod 5 = 1 $

$3\color{red}{+}4 = (3+4)\bmod 5 = 2 $

---

$4\color{red}{+}0 = (4+0)\bmod 5 = 4 = 0\color{red}{+}4 $

$4\color{red}{+}1 = (4+1)\bmod 5 = 0 = 1\color{red}{+}4 $

$4\color{red}{+}2 = (4+2)\bmod 5 = 1 = 2\color{red}{+}4$

$4\color{red}{+}3 = (4+3)\bmod 5 = 2 = 3\color{red}{+}4 $

$4\color{red}{+}4 = (4+4)\bmod 5 = 3 $

---

Or in a so called [Cayley's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table):

[image]

---

**(1) neutral or identity element** of $G$ with respect to the operation $\color{red}{+}$ is $0 \in G$

$\forall a \in G:~ ~a\color{red}{+}0=a=0\color{red}{+}a. $

Because we have the following (see first line in each block of calculation or first row and first column in the cayley's table):

$0\color{red}{+}0 = 0 $, $1\color{red}{+}0 = 1 = 0\color{red}{+}1$ , $2\color{red}{+}0 = 2 = 0\color{red}{+}2$ , $3\color{red}{+}0 = 3 = 0\color{red}{+}3$ and $4\color{red}{+}0 = 4 = 0\color{red}{+}4$

---

**(2) Inverse element** of each element $\in G$ has to be also $\in G$

$\forall a \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}:~  \exists b \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}:~ ~a\color{red}{+}b=0=b\color{red}{+}a $

Because we have the following (see the lines in each calculation block, where there's "a $0$ in the middle", see also "the $0$ diagonale" in the cayley's table):

$0\color{red}{+}0 = 0= 0\color{red}{+}0,  3\color{red}{+}2 = 0= 2\color{red}{+}3$ and $1\color{red}{+}4 = 0= 4\color{red}{+}1$

---

**(3) Closure with respect to the group operation/law** $\color{red}{+}$

The group operation/law is a function $$\color{red}{+}: G \times G \rightarrow G, x \color{red}{+} y = (x+y) \bmod 5$$, which means that $G$ has to be closed under it's operation. So, $\color{red}{+}$ operates ([a binary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)) on two arguments $x \in G$ and $y \in G$. Then it gives an element $x\color{red}{+}y$ back, which has to be again in $G$.

---

**(4)  Associativity with respect to the group operation/law** $\color{red}{+}$

Assume $a,b,c \in G$, then

$(a\color{red}{+}b)\color{red}{+}c=((a+b)\bmod 5 )\color{red}{+}c=(((a+b)\bmod 5)+c)\bmod 5 $

and

$a\color{red}{+}(b\color{red}{+}c)=a\color{red}{+}((b+c) \bmod 5 )=(a+((b+c)\bmod 5))\bmod 5$

So, if $(a\color{red}{+}b)\color{red}{+}c=a\color{red}{+}(b\color{red}{+}c)$ or if $G$ is associative, then $$(((a+b)\bmod 5)+c)\bmod 5 =(a+((b+c)\bmod 5))\bmod 5 $$
has to be true. This $(a+b)\bmod 5+c\equiv a+(b+c)\bmod 5 ~ ~(\bmod 5) $ can be shown using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Or it can also be shown using the [light's associativity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light%27s_associativity_test) using the caley's table.

---

We can also see, that this group is commutative ($a+b=b+a$, symmetric cayley's table), which means that this group is a special group, it's an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group).

---

**A sub group** $H < G$ of a group $G$ has to satisfy all the four group properties or **has to be a group for itself with respect to the same group operation** $\color{red}{+}$.

Assume $H = \{0,1,4\}$. Then $4 \color{red}{+} 4 = (4+4) \bmod 5 = 3 \not\in H$ and $1 \color{red}{+} 1 = (1+1) \bmod 5 = 2 \not\in H$. $H$ is therefore not closed with respect to $\color{red}{+}$.

Maybe if we look close enough in the cayley's table, we might find a subgroup? But I don't think so, according to the [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) and due to the fact that $ | H | = 3 \nmid 5 = | G | $.

For example here is a picture about other abelian groups from the wikipedia article about subgroups. The operation here is $\color{red}{+}: G \times G \rightarrow G, x\color{red}{+}y = (x+y) \bmod 8$

[image]

If $G$ is a (n abelian) groub, then $H$ is a (n abelian) subgroub.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest subgroup containing $1$, should also contains $1+1, 1+1+1, 1+1+1+1 \dots$ and also their inverses.